# Reading ASCII text file using an std::ifstream in C++

Tags: c++, character-encoding, ifstream

I have an Arabic file (ASCII), which contains:
121101  الزبون كمال 
121102  الزبون سعيد 
121103  الزبون عمار

I want to read this file using an std::ifstream in C++ as:

```
std::ifstream ifs(file.GetFileName());
std::string content((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

When I had watched  a content variable using VS IDE, I got a character encoding error:
121101  ÇáÒÈæä ßãÇá
121102  ÇáÒÈæä ÓÚíÏ
121103  ÇáÒÈæä ÚãÇÑ

Also I have tray an std::wifstream:

```
std::wifstream ifs2(file.GetFileName());
std::string content2((std::istreambuf_iterator<wchar_t>(ifs2)), std::istreambuf_iterator<wchar_t>());
```

I have got the same error.
Could anybody help me?
Thank.

Comment: ASCII has no arabic characters. Figure out what encoding it actually is and read it as that, but `iostream`s are not very good for that, so you might want to use an OS-specific function or some other library to do that for you.

Comment: As I know ASCII has a code page parameter, how can I pass this parameter to ifstream !!

Comment: You can do that using `wifstream::imbue()` method, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have an Arabic file (ASCII), which contains: 121101 الزبون كمال
>   121102 الزبون سعيد 121103 الزبون عمار

After some clarification, OP wants:

> to write general function which read uft8 and ANSI files

To be able to treat the content in the same way, I suggest converting to an UTF-16 encoded `std::wstring`. OP seems to develop for the Windows platform, where UTF-16 is the encoding expected by most APIs. On other platforms (Linux) it might be more suitable to convert everything to UTF-8 instead.

## Reading ANSI text file into UTF-16 encoded wstring

To be able to decode ANSI (aka extended ASCII), we have to know the [codepage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page) of the file.

The codepage (or more precisely the locale) can be defined via the stream's [`imbue()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/imbue) method. In your case the code page is [1256](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc195058.aspx).

The following example reads the content of a text file that is encoded with ANSI codepage 1256 and displays the text using `MessageBoxW()` which expects an UTF-16 encoded string:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <codecvt>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    // Use wifstream because we want to read content into a wstring.
    std::wifstream f{"test.txt"};

    // Define the code page of the text file (1256 = Arabic)
    f.imbue( std::locale( ".1256" ) );

    // Read the whole file into a wstring.
    // The stream converts from ANSI to UTF-16 encoding.
    std::wstring s{ std::istreambuf_iterator<wchar_t>( f ), std::istreambuf_iterator<wchar_t>() };

    // Display the string which is now UTF-16 encoded.    
    ::MessageBoxW( NULL, s.c_str(), L"test", 0 );

    return 0;
}
```

**NOTE**: The `std::locale` parameter is platform specific. ".1256" works on the Windows platform, but this would propably not work on Linux for instance.

## Reading UTF-8 encoded text file into UTF-16 encoded wstring

For this we can employ the [`std::codecvt_utf8_utf16`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf8_utf16) facet. 
Replace the [`imbue()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/imbue) call of the previous example with the following code:

```
    f.imbue( std::locale( f.getloc(), 
        new std::codecvt_utf8_utf16< wchar_t, 1114111UL, std::consume_header> ) );
```

The flag `std::consume_header` skips the [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) if it exists.

**Notes:**

- The code samples have been tested with VS2017 under Windows 10 with german localization.
- For brevity I omitted error handling. Stream state should be checked after opening and after reading from the stream.

## Creating a generic solution

The code samples presented above require you to know the encoding of the text files beforehand. Detecting the encoding of a text file in a truly generic way is a hard task because there is no standard way of doing that. It cannot be done reliably, you'd have to use some heuristics.

If you can make some assumptions about the files you have to handle, you can write a simple detection function though. Say the files fall only into the following categories:

- ANSI encoded file with code page 1256
- UTF-8 encoded file with BOM ([byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark))

Then you could read the first 3 bytes of the file using `std::ifstream` and compare them with `{0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF}`. If equal, you could be relatively sure that the file is UTF-8 encoded because it will be unlikely that a non-UTF-8 encoded file begins with these bytes. If not equal, you would assume code page 1256.

Comment: Thanks @zett42
Your code is worked correctly, but why when I try the imbu method as:
std::ifstream ifs("test.txt");
ifs.imbue( std::locale( ".1256" ) );
std::string content((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

It's not worked ?!!!!!

Comment: @Bassam if you use `ifstream` instead of `wifstream` there is no conversion, so `imbue()` doesn't do anything. You get the string with the same encoding as in the file. What do you want to do with `content`?

Comment: @Bassam I read under the other answer _My function sometimes read a utf8 file, and sometimes read an ASCII file_. I can add an example to read UTF-8 file with `wifstream` if you like.

Comment: My objective is to write a general function which read a uft8,ANSI, unicode files and put the entire file content into the content variable, is this possible, may there is a way to determine file encoding? or must I write multi functions for that? 
Also please modify your answer to include an example for UTF-8 file reading :)

Answer (score -3):

Why don't you use FILE* instead? For instance this is an excerpt from my code where I am reading the save.ini for my game which contains different save game entries. What I like about fopen () is that you can actually tell which format the file has (like UTF-8, UTF-16 etc.).

```
FILE* pFini = fopen ("save\\save.ini", "rt,ccs=UTF-8");
int iLine = 0;

if (pFini == NULL)
{
    cout << "WARNING: cannot open save.ini file." << endl;
    return;
}

while (!feof (pFini))
{
    fgetws (wSaveGames [iLine], 125, pFini);
    iLine++;
    if (iLine >= MAX_SAVEGAME_NUMBER)
        break;
}
fclose (pFini);
```

Comment: Question is tagged `c++` and `ifstream`, so coming up with a C solution is not helpful.

Comment: Pfft, trying to help with my knowledge here. What works for c will also work for c++. Personally I am using both, why not.

Comment: My function sometimes read a utf8 file, and sometimes read an ASCII file, so I have used an ifstream and std::string.